# using From trait to trigger converting u8 to enum

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
enum ValueType {
    k1,
    k2,
    kUnknown,
}

impl ValueType {
    fn value(&self) -> u8 {
        match *self {
            ValueType::k1 => 0x0,
            ValueType::k2 => 0x1,
            ValueType::kUnknown => 0xff,
        }
    }
}

impl From<u8> for ValueType {
    fn from(orig: u8) -> Self {
        match orig {
            0x0 => return ValueType::k1,
            0x1 => return ValueType::k2,
            _ => return ValueType::kUnknown,
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: ValueType = 0x0 as u8; // error, expected enum `ValueType`, found u8
}
```

I would like to convert `u8` to `ValueType`. How do I do it in Rust way?

Comment: There is the [num_enum crate](https://crates.io/crates/num_enum) which can safe a lot of manual writing code

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0db2d36ef4bfbd78aa4e21ebe5d0fe39).

Comment: @hellow Thanks for mentioning num_enum. It looks like the best crate for this type of thing because it provides a derive macro that actually implements `std::convert` traits (rather than for instance creating an unnecessary new trait or associated function). Somehow I didn't run across it when searching crates.io.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::convert::Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) is automatically implemented for you as a complementary trait to `From` so you could use its provided method and the following will compile just fine.  (`Into::into`, unlike `From::from` is a method and not an associated function.)

```rust
fn main() {
    let a: ValueType = 0x0u8.into();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the associated from() method that you already implemented:

```
...
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
...

fn main() {
    let a = ValueType::from(0x0u8);
    let b: ValueType = 0x0u8.into();
    assert_eq!(a,b);
}
```